# Swiper get last search term

Tags: search, ivy, swiper

How to get [swiper](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) to search for **the last searched term** , much like (default) `isearch-forward` does when pressing `C-s` twice?

Comment: Actually this is by default works the way you want... Just press `C-s`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you invoke swiper press `M-p` to search for previously searched thing.

`M-n` will let you search for the word under cursor.

`C-s` will search for the next occurence.

**UPD**, thx @Basil

After you invoke the `swiper` press `C-s` to search for a previously searched string. Press `C-s` again to go to the next occurrence.

Comment: You should mention that `C-s` (`ivy-next-line-or-history`) will either select the previous history element on empty input or move N matches forward, as you allude to in [your comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40556/swiper-get-last-search-term#comment63498_40556).

Comment: @yPhil you You should make it clear that you're just looking for a way to get the last searched term, under any key and not just that which you used to invoke `swiper`.

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, here is my swiper config right now.

- I can search the rightmost expression(s) by pressing repeatedly `C-f` ;
- I can search the "last term" by pressing `C-f C-s` (thanks @maxim-kim) and ;
- I can access *both recent files and opened buffers* by pressing f4 :)
- And I still have C-s bound to `isearch` for macros and such.

.

```
(use-package ivy-hydra
  :ensure t)

(use-package swiper
  :ensure try
  :bind
  (([f4] . ivy-switch-buffer)
   ([(control c) (f)] . counsel-ag)
   ([(control c) (g)] . counsel-git)
   ([(control c) (j)] . counsel-git-grep)
   ([(control c) (l)] . counsel-locate)
   ([(control d)] . swiper-ag)
   ([(control f)] . swiper)
   ([(control h) (control f)] . counsel-describe-function)
   ([(control h) (control v)] . counsel-describe-variable)
   ([(control o)] . counsel-find-file)
   ([(control shift o)] . counsel-recentf)
   ([f9] . counsel-rhythmbox)
   :map ivy-minibuffer-map
   ([(control f)] . ivy-yank-word)
   :map read-expression-map
   ([(control r)] . counsel-expression-history))
  :config
  (progn
    (define-key
      ivy-switch-buffer-map
      [(control w)]
      (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (ivy-set-action 'kill-buffer)
        (ivy-done))))
  :init
  (setq  ivy-use-virtual-buffers t
         ivy-ignore-buffers '("\\` " "\\`\\*")
         ivy-display-style 'fancy
         ivy-count-format "(%d/%d) "
         ivy-initial-inputs-alist nil
         ivy-extra-directories nil))

(use-package try
  :ensure t)
```